# Not able to collapse panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap to have a collapsible panel.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Amérique du nord/North America <span data-toggle="collapse" target-target="#panelBodyOne" class="collapsed">+</span></div>
            <div id="panelBodyOne" class="panel-body collapse"> Test</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your target attribute named as `target-target` but it should be `data-target`.

```
<span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panelBodyOne" class="collapsed">+</span>
```

Comment: @kot09 no worries! We all have our off days sometimes :D Do me a favour and mark this as a correct answers?

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-target` attribute on your span Tag

try this code

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Amérique du nord/North America 
     <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panelBodyOne"    
       class="collapsed">+</span>
    </div>
            <div id="panelBodyOne" class="panel-body collapse">Test</div>
      </div>
</div>
```